# Историческая грамматика

Tags: лексика, общие-вопросы, история

Может ли кто-нибудь подсказать, где можно найти материалы о лексике средневекового права в древнерусских памятниках письменности?

Answer (score 4):

Текст "Русской правды" академическое издание 1846 г. - [можно как скачать, так и читать онлайн](http://www.runivers.ru/lib/book7831/452082/)
Академическое издание 1935 г. (на украинском) - [читать](http://litopys.org.ua/)
Краткая редакция (с параллельным переводом) - [читать](http://lib.pushkinskijdom.ru/Default.aspx?tabid=4946)
Пространная редакция (с параллельным переводом) - [читать](http://lib.pushkinskijdom.ru/Default.aspx?tabid=4947)
Интересные материалы, связанные с Русской правдой - http://russkaya-pravda.ru/

Судебник 1497 г. - [читать](http://krotov.info/acts/16/2/pravo_01.htm)

Судебник 1550 г. (академическое издание 1768 г.) - [читать или скачать](https://books.google.ru/books?id=9G9BAAAAYAAJ&pg=PR20&hl=ru#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Соборное уложение 1649 г. - [читать](http://www.hist.msu.ru/ER/Etext/1649.htm)

Это, в основном, непосредственно тексты. Если нужен анализ, то придётся поискать самой.

Answer (score 2):

Есть такая книга: Улуханов И.С. О языке Древней Руси. Изд.4, испр. и доп. 2015., а в ней небольшой раздел (10 стр.) "Деловой язык Древней Руси".

Может быть, там есть что-нибудь подходящее.